# Get PartialView to render part using Jquery within Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, razor

I have controller which return PartialView. Also I have javascript that catch this return by result to do something. But here is problem.

make this result to show text (result.responseText), I got weird HTML code.

```
<$A$> <div</$A$><$B$> class="container"</$B$><$C$> id="regi"</$C$><$D$>> </$D$><$E$> </$E$><$F$><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="VKMPnUu9UA3ikkIA9o6mBPks6TNIpbNkwUtulJiWP-YOuKyYcXxyCknqCf_YAvyj1BGVZJHRBqLtjIttcFFENjgbx_RrttQZcgUJh8Lxb5w1" /></$F$><$G$> <h4>Create a new account.aassss</h4> <hr /> </$G$><$H$> </$H$><$I$><div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li>The Password must be at least 6 characters long.</li> </ul></div></$I$><$J$> <div</$J$><$K$> class="form-group"</$K$><$L$>> </$L$><$M$> </$M$><$N$><label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="UserName">User name</label></$N$><$O$> <div</$O$><$P$> class="col-md-10"</$P$><$Q$>> </$Q$><$R$> </$R$><$S$><input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="User name 필드가 필요합니다." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="asd" /></$S$><$T$> </div> </div> <div</$T$><$U$> class="form-group"</$U$><$V$>> </$V$><$W$> </$W$><$X$><label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Password">Password</label></$X$><$Y$> <div</$Y$><$Z$> class="col-md-10"</$Z$><$a$>> </$a$><$b$> </$b$><$c$><input class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="The Password must be at least 6 characters long." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="Password 필드가 필요합니다." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" /></$c$><$d$> </div> </div> <div</$d$><$e$> class="form-group"</$e$><$f$>> </$f$><$g$> </$g$><$h$><label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm password</label></$h$><$i$> <div</$i$><$j$> class="col-md-10"</$j$><$k$>> </$k$><$l$> </$l$><$m$><input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="&#39;Confirm password&#39;과(와) &#39;Password&#39;이(가) 일치하지 않습니다." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" type="password" /></$m$><$n$> </div> </div> </div> </$n$><$o$> </$o$><$p$> </$p$><$q$> </$q$><$$$><map><file path="~/Views/Shared/_Register.cshtml" encoding="ks_c_5601-1987"><node id="A" start="46" length="10" literal="true" /><node id="B" start="56" length="18" literal="true" /><node id="C" start="74" length="10" literal="true" /><node id="D" start="84" length="3" literal="true" /><node id="E" start="87" length="8" literal="true" /><node id="F" start="96" length="23" /><node id="G" start="119" length="64" literal="true" /><node id="H" start="183" length="8" literal="true" /><node id="I" start="192" length="24" /><node id="J" start="216" length="14" literal="true" /><node id="K" start="230" length="19" literal="true" /><node id="L" start="249" length="3" literal="true" /><node id="M" start="252" length="12" literal="true" /><node id="N" start="265" length="73" /><node id="O" start="338" length="18" literal="true" /><node id="P" start="356" length="18" literal="true" /><node id="Q" start="374" length="3" literal="true" /><node id="R" start="377" length="16" literal="true" /><node id="S" start="394" length="65" /><node id="T" start="459" length="50" literal="true" /><node id="U" start="509" length="19" literal="true" /><node id="V" start="528" length="3" literal="true" /><node id="W" start="531" length="12" literal="true" /><node id="X" start="544" length="73" /><node id="Y" start="617" length="18" literal="true" /><node id="Z" start="635" length="18" literal="true" /><node id="a" start="653" length="3" literal="true" /><node id="b" start="656" length="16" literal="true" /><node id="c" start="673" length="66" /><node id="d" start="739" length="50" literal="true" /><node id="e" start="789" length="19" literal="true" /><node id="f" start="808" length="3" literal="true" /><node id="g" start="811" length="12" literal="true" /><node id="h" start="824" length="80" /><node id="i" start="904" length="18" literal="true" /><node id="j" start="922" length="18" literal="true" /><node id="k" start="940" length="3" literal="true" /><node id="l" start="943" length="16" literal="true" /><node id="m" start="960" length="73" /><node id="n" start="1033" length="60" literal="true" /><node id="o" start="2128" length="4" literal="true" /><node id="p" start="6409" length="10" literal="true" /><node id="q" start="7537" length="2" literal="true" /></file></map>
```

Please can anyone help me on this to make real HTML? or Doing something wrong in this code?

```
$("#Register").click(function (e) {
        var str = $("form").serialize();
        //var model = form.serialize();
        //$("#test").text(str);
        $.ajax({
            url: RegisterURL.RegisterUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: 'false',
            data: str,
            dataType: "json",
            sucess: function (result) {
                alert("asdad");
                //$("#myModal").html(result);
            },
            error: function (result, status) {
                alert("Fails");
                $("#test").text(result.responseText);
                $("#Content").html(result.responseText);
                var urlAct = '@Url.Action("Register","Account")'
                alert(result);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Here is

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                        return Json("Success");

                    //return Json
                    //return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    AddErrors(result);
                    //if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                    //{
                    //    return Json(new { message = "Fail" });
                    //}
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return PartialView("_Register",model);
        }
```

Comment: I assume that is a typo, but you have `sucess` instead of `success` for the ajax handler.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataType: "text"` and not `dataType: json` as the expected result from the server is HTML and not JSON.

Your server code actually returns either a simple JSON string of "success" or HTML, so you need to also not return a JSON result for the success case (just return plain text).

You also have a typo mentioned in comment:

`sucess` => `success`